# BBQ Horror madness

Tags: horror

Hi all,

I'm working on a short horror film at the moment and I have quite a gruesome scene where a person falls face first onto a BBQ which results in some face melting gruesomeness. I've already made a start on it and have some nice effects in place but I just thought i'd see if you guys could give me anymore ideas for this scene and how you would approach it.

To set the scene the kid falls face first onto the bbq and then pulls away melting and tearing his skin in the process.

Thank,

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi,

These kind of sounds are so much fun to make. I have done this before and I used anti-acid powder for some of the burn sound. I put it in a plate to make it breath with some water. I also added a fried egg and rice falling through my hand to show that the heat is burning through his skin. For the tearing off, I used the same fried egg which I allowed to over cook and stick to the pan and I then tore it off- really yummy and very effective. I also added the general raw meat (ie raw and cooked chicken skin being tore off the meat. A hot iron or piece of metal in about 10mm of water is also very effective. Experiment and have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Watch the scene in terminator 2 where Arnie throws the biker on the grill because he wont give him his clothes.  Its near the beginning of the movie.  The sound in it was really good and made you feel like the guy got burned really bad.  The sounds were not over the top but it conveyed the message.

Benjie

Answer (score 0):

Just throw a tiny but of water in a fat pan!! But caution it will spread things away :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used a soldering iron on a pork chop for flesh-burning sounds before. Can sound pretty cool.